# selfhosted WebAPI runs in IDE, but not outside of IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have a selfhosted WebAPI built into a console app.  When I run it via the VisualStudio IDE, everything works fine.  I have a client app that connects and interacts with the WebAPI app just fine.  However, if I run my WebAPI app outside of the IDE, by just double clicking the EXE, my client app is unable to connect to it at all.  I do not get any real useful error information either, there are two InnerExceptions in the client (on the PostAsXmlAsync call).  One says "Unable to connect to remote server", and the 2nd is "An error occurred while sending the request".

Normally, I'd troubleshoot and debug this myself if it were a consistent error.  But the key element here is if I run this all via the VisualStudio IDE, everything works as expected.

Can anyone provide some suggestions on what I should be looking at/for?  Thanx!

Comment: Running Visual Studio as admin? However, insert a break point through code in your main method (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() I think), then your program will ask you to attach a debugger, and you can then attach your Visual Studio. (You start your program outside of Visual Studio when you do this.) This will allow you to debug your program as it would behave when not started through Visual Studio

Comment: ARGH!!!  Thank you.  I knew about Running everything as Adnmin, but I have my VS start up automagically as asmin, so I always forget to Run As Admin applications outside of VS.  An obvious answer I should've thought of.  Thank you.

Comment: @Abdul Ahad Monty - please stop using code tags for things that aren't code. Edits like these are minor, unhelpful, and clog up the suggested edit queue. [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1611352#./1611352?&_suid=136197691857801701066037251212) was rejected.

Answer (score 1):

1) If all you are doing is accessing the self host locally, you can set the following configuration option:

```
config.HostNameComparisonMode = System.ServiceModel.HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
```

With that, you don't have to run the process with elevated privileges (again, if you want to access it locally).

2) Another option is to reserve a specific port for the specific user:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:999/ user=machine\username
```

That also allows you to run self host not as admin, as long as the process is started for a user for whom the port has been reserved.

3) Finally, the last option is to just run it as admin.